# DB Driver for azure SQL Data ware house via python notebook in ML Studio

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, jupyter-notebook, sql-data-warehouse, ml-studio

I am trying to access my data warehouse azure, fetch some data in mlstudio-attached-notebook in python. Simple connection says driver not found.

[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect).

Now, I need to know, is it a firewall issue or the not right driver name issue.

I have tried multiple driver name/string. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at issue with php, one of the guy suggested the driver name.

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/526

Driver is "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"

Answer (score 0):

1. Install ODBC driver manager from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-driver-manager).
2. Download ODBC Driver for Linux from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/system-requirements).
3. Install the ODBC driver as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).
4. Install pyodbc and the required packages

   sudo apt-get -y install python-pip

   sudo pip install --upgrade pip

   sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

   sudo apt-get install python-dev

   sudo pip install pyodbc

Finally, run the following Python script to test.

```
import pyodbc
server = 'tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net'
database = 'mydb'
username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypass'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print row
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```